NextJS authentication with separate backend (How to make subsequent http-requests to token-protected routes)
I've googled enough. Almost every topic-related guide on the Internet ends after showing example of storing token into cookies and maybe session refresh example. But for me, the most interesting (and hard) part comes after - when I want to make http-requests to token-protected routes.
In the context of making http-requests in my project, the main agents are:

Remote backend server (supports Authorization via Authorization header OR user_token cookie)
NextJS (server-side)
NextJS (client-side)

Desired auth flow:

User fills a form with email and password, request is sent from nextjs client to nextjs server via server action;
NextJS server makes http request to remote backend, and, if status ok, sets a http-only "user_token" cookie via { cookies } from 'next/headers' and sends response back to client;
From now on, I want to be able to make http-requests to backend's protected routes (token required) both from NextJS server side and NextJS client side.

So there is my list of questions:
a) I've noticed that for http-requests from NextJS server side using NextJS fetch() function, credentials: "include" does not include my previously set cookie. So I guess before every request I need to get token with cookies().get("user_token")?.value. Is that right or there is a way to make credentials: "include" work?
b) If (in production) NextJS server and Backend server will run on the same domain, would my NextJS client-side requests automatically include "user_token" cookie?
c) While in dev mode, is there anything I can do in order to set "user_token" cookie both for localhost:3000 (nextJS server) and backend domain? Or I should just manually set it every time while I am developing? (Currently in dev mode "user_token" sets for localhost:3000 and therefore cookie is not sent when making request directly from client-side to backend).
Notes:

On NextJS server side I am making http-requests to backend only via NextJS fetch() function.
On NextJS client side I am making http-requests to backend only via apisauce instance (it is basically axios).

I will include some code listings, but context of my question can be understood without looking at them.
login server action (simplified code):
export const loginAction = async (state: unknown, formData: unknown): Promise<LoginFormState> => {
  if (!(formData instanceof FormData)) 
    return {
      message: "Invalid payload",
      ok: false
    };

  // Validate form fields
  const validatedFields = LoginFormSchema.safeParse({
    email: formData.get('email'),
    password: formData.get('password'),
  })
 
  // If any form fields are invalid, return early
  if (!validatedFields.success) {
    console.log('validation error');
    return {
      errors: validatedFields.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
    } as LoginFormState
  }

  const loginResponse = await loginPost({
    ...validatedFields.data
  });

  if (!classicNextApiResponseValidator(loginResponse)) {
    const error = await requestErrorFromNextResponse(loginResponse);
    return {
      message: error.description,
      ok: false
    }
  }

  const responseData: T.LoginResponse = await loginResponse.json();
       
  await storeToCookies("user_token", responseData.accessToken);

  if (responseData.emailVerified) {
    await redirectAction("/dashboard", {});
  } else {
    await redirectAction("/emailVerification", {});
  }
 
  return {
    message: "successfully",
    ok: true
  }
};

storeToCookies Function
"use server";

import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { CookiesKey } from './types';

export const storeToCookies = async <T = any>(key: CookiesKey, value: T, options: {} = {}) => {
  if (typeof key === "string")
    cookies().set(
      key,
      typeof value === "string" ? value : JSON.stringify(value),
      {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
      }
    );
};

My attempt to make request to protected route (profile) from nextJS server side (credentials: "include" does not work, but manually getting cookie and passing it as header works:
export const profileGet = async () => { 
  return fetch(`${CONFIG.BASE_URL}/profile`, { 
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: DEFAULT_HEADERS,
  });
};


My apisauce instance for client-side requests:
const sauce = create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: CONFIG.BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  }
});


By default, cookies are not passed in a server-side fetch call for security reasons.
That's why we should pass headers to the fetch call.
import { headers } from "next/headers"

//...
//...
//...
async function getProfile() {
    const response = fetch(`${CONFIG.BASE_URL}/profile`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers(),
    })
    
    if (!response.ok) return null

    return res.json()
}

const PageHome: React.FC<PageHomeProps> = async () => {
    const profile = await getProfile()
    
    //...
    //...
    //...
}

export default PageHome


I feel like passing ALL headers to fetch() is a bit too much and kinda insecure, I'd prefer to pass only the cookies that I need ("user_token" cookie and that's it).
So my "a" question is: if I do it with cookies().get("user_token") in each fetch() would it be okay?
